# What is the code for renaming non-space filename

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a filename of document erwin_01problem.doc, What i want here is the if a filename does not contain a space between **01problem** (erwin_0**1p**roblem.doc). I find the index of problem and replace it with  " ". The output will be **erwin_01 problem.doc**
Here is the code that i try but still I wasn't able to put a space between 01 and problem.

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(job.ProblemPath))
            {
                job.HasProblemFile = true;
                var problemDocFname = Path.GetFileName(job.ProblemPath);
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(problemDocFname, @"\sproblem\.doc$"))
                {
                    ProgM.JobStatus = "Checking space between filename and problem...";
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    problemDocFname = problemDocFname.Insert(problemDocFname.IndexOf("problem.doc", StringComparison.Ordinal), " ");
                    //problemDocFname = problemDocFname.Replace("problem", " problem");
                }
                problemDocFname = Path.Combine(job.FilePath, problemDocFname);
                var docProblemCount = 0;
                ProgM.JobStatus = "Correcting the Format of Problem Doc...";
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                MicrosoftWord.CorrectProblemDocFormatting(problemDocFname, ref docProblemCount);
            }
            jobs.Add(job);
```

Comment: Please describe how it "didn't succeed".

Comment: @Richard, I already edit my question, I want to put a space between 01 and problem if I found filename of document without space between 01 and problem.

Comment: Why not just:
var problemDocFname = Path.GetFileName(job.ProblemPath);
(...)
problemDocFname.replace("problem.doc", " problem.doc");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I belive you don't really need  regular expressions. You can just do something like:

```
string key = "problem.doc";
if (problemDocFname.EndsWith(key) && problemDocFname.Length > key.Length)
{
      problemDocFname.Replace(key, " problem.doc");
}
```